# LiteDb v5 Query.All() equivalent

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, litedb

What is the `BsonExpression` equivalent of `Query.All()` in LiteDb v5?

I'm having trouble finding `BsonExpression` that translates to 'all results'. I have a helper class that generates `Query` in LiteDb v4. So I'm trying to port my helper class to be able to work with LiteDb v5. In LiteDb v4, `Find` method of a `LiteCollection` accepts `Query` object, but in v5 it accepts `BsonExpression` object.

Using `FindAll()` method is not an option for the purpose of this helper class, since I'm migrating my application from LiteDb v4 to v5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, I'm using `Query.Not("_id", null);`, which returns a `BsonExpression`. Since Id field will never be null, this is good enough for now, but I would still like to do things proper way.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, plese donot forget to mark your answer after three days, if will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: But doesn't this prevent you from doing Query.Descending?